# Hide inline images and show links in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, images

On using an image link as,

```
[[./hello.png]]
```

in `org-mode`, emacs doesn't toggle the inline image display. `org-toggle-inline-images` works well on start-up. I run a presentation using `M-x epresent-run` [epresent](https://github.com/eschulte/epresent) and come back to edit mode from the presentation mode by pressing `q`. Then the image display stops toggling.

## What I get after quitting `epresent-mode`:

[image: image-display-on]

## What I want:

[image]

This behavior is seen after I get into presentation mode using [epresent](https://github.com/eschulte/epresent) and come back to edit mode by pressing `q`.

Comment: This isn't the default behavior. Look into your init file for mentions of either `org-toggle-inline-images` (newer Org) or `org-toggle-iimage-in-org` (older Org). Also see this link: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-configs/org-config-examples.html - this is probably how you get it in the first place.

Comment: this command works before i run `epresent-run` but after going into presentation mode & coming mode, toggling stops

Comment: I think that toggling depends on some text property which Org puts in this kind of links. Probably presentation mode wipes all such properties. I'd write to epresent maintainers about the problem. They'd be the ones to know how to work around it.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug to be filed on `epresent-mode`.

Comment: i already raised one github issue - : https://github.com/eschulte/epresent/issues/23

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To toggle images, do either:

```
C-c C-x C-v
```

or

```
M-x org-toggle-inline-images
```

To do this in `#+OPTIONS`, it looks like you can set it in the `#+STARTUP:` https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-Settings.html - see `inlineimages` and `noinlineimages`

Comment: This is not a real answer to the question of the connection between `epresent` and `org-mode`.

Comment: @Tobias I did the best I could do here - if you have a superior response, please provide it and I will certainly upvote you if I can tell it is good.

Comment: It was [actually a bug that is apparently already resolved](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9872/hide-inline-images-and-show-links-in-org-mode/24618?noredirect=1#comment14797_9872).